# Rails: working with calculated values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two calculated values **subtotal** and **shipment charges** and a third one **total** which is the sum of the first two. I want to display all three of them in the View. How can I do this. What I am doing right now does not seem good.

```
    Subtotal: <%= @cart.subtotal %>
    Shipment: <%= @cart.shipment_charges %>
    Total: <%= @cart.subtotal + @cart.shipment_charges %>
```

The last is calling the methods again to get the final total. What is the best practice for this?

Also storing the results like this in the view also looks bad

```
    <%- subtotal = @cart.subtotal %>
    <%- shipment_charges = @cart.shipment_charges %>
    ...
    Total: <%= subtotal + shipment_charges %>
```

Please help

Answer (score 3):

Since you are dealing with invoices, don't you want to save those values?

If not, you should be using virtual attributes:

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  def total
    subtotal + shipment_charges
  end

end
```

Check [this link](http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/4-add-model-virtual-attribute) for a detailed example.

Answer (score 0):

1. good practice is prepare your instance variable in controller
2. there you can make your sum as well

Answer (score 0):

I'm not convinced that what you are doing is bad practice.  Generally you should try and keep business logic out of your views, but what you are doing here is simply presentation of data.

Unless you are planning on sending the `Total` back to the database, it's not really a big deal.

If you are using the subtotal, shipment_charges and total elsewhere you could declare them as a calculated field on your model.

e.g.

```
Class Cart ...

  def total_cost
    self.subtotal + self.shipment_charges
  end

end
```

That way you can just call @cart.total_cost in your view

Comment: I have to show all three values in the view. So `@cart.total_cost` will be doing the same calculation again that was already done for `@cart.subtotal` and `@cart.shipment_charges`